How to crop AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
There's a few posts around this but are all quite out-dated. Furthermore, I'm using SwiftUI and would like to adopt the solution to be usable in a SwiftUI environment. I should preface by saying that I don't know much about UIKit.
I'm trying to crop a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to a small box in the middle of the screen. I'd like to be able to use it like a normal SwiftUI view like:
CameraPreview()
  .frame(width: 200, height: 200)

Here's my MRE. In this setup, the preview is shifted to the bottom right of the screen:
class CameraViewController: UIViewController {
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo
        
        guard let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
        
        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
            if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                captureSession.addInput(input)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
        previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        view.layer.addSublayer(at: previewLayer)
        
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
}

struct CameraView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CameraViewController {
        return CameraViewController()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CameraViewController, context: Context) {}
}

Another approach I've tried is using a mask:
CameraView()
    .mask(
        Rectangle()
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .opacity(0.0)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .opacity(1)
            )
    )

This looks fine except it's still actually taking up the whole screen, masking gesture inputs to the background views.
Furthermore, I need to be able to actually capture photos in this box, I can manually crop the captured photo using:
func crop(toPreviewLayer layer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, withRect rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
        let outputRect = layer.metadataOutputRectConverted(fromLayerRect: rect)
        var cgImage = self.cgImage!
        let width = CGFloat(cgImage.width)
        let height = CGFloat(cgImage.height)
        let cropRect = CGRect(
            x: outputRect.origin.x * width,
            y: outputRect.origin.y * height,
            width: outputRect.size.width * width,
            height: outputRect.size.height * height)

        cgImage = cgImage.cropping(to: cropRect)!
        let croppedUIImage = UIImage(
            cgImage: cgImage,
            scale: self.scale,
            orientation: self.imageOrientation
        )

        return croppedUIImage
    }

But layer.metadataOutputRectConverted(fromLayerRect: rect) does not work if I'm using a mask.
This seems like a very common use case but I'm going nuts trying to find a solution.
